# connect to remote mysql server from google cloud

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I have a google cloud machine which has an ubuntu Os, I have MySQL database on another server, I opened the remote connection on my SQL server, and I connect to my database from any machine else from my google cloud machine I can not, it taking long time then I have a timeout connection problem.
I think the problem is from firewall rules, so I applied this command to create rule that allow 3306 port

```
cloud compute firewall-rules create "mysql-remote-access" --allow tcp:3306 --source-tags "mysql-client" --target-tags "mysql-server"
```

but still, I can not connect to a remote MySQL server
from where  can I enable it, thank you

Comment: Do you use internal of external IP to connect to MySQL? Please Provide more details about your network topology.

Comment: thank you for reply , I am using external IP , My database is hosted on another server out side of google cloud network

Comment: my database is hosted on xx.xx.xx.xx ip which is totally outside googled cloud , and I am trying to access this database from my google cloud instance , but I can not , I tried from my local machine to access database and  it is connected without any problem

Comment: in google cloud's server I opened remote mysql database , and try to access the MySQL database remotely and  I can , and  I can access the database in cloud's server from my xx.xx.xx.xx server , but can not access database in xx.xx.xx.xx from cloud's server

Comment: so what is happening is I can access from xx.xx.xx.xx to cloud's server but can not in reverse status  ,(access database in xx.xx.xx.xx from cloud's server) , the xx.xx.xx.xx has cpanel , so I don't know if it has any rule to prevent cloud from access it

Comment: " the xx.xx.xx.xx has cpanel , so I don't know if it has any rule to prevent cloud from access it" does it mean that your database managed by some company?

Comment: No it is managed by me, but as I am not expert in cpanel , so I am thinking in this idea

Comment: the problem is I can access database from any another machine or server outside google cloud

Comment: I don't understand you firewall rule. You want to reach the port 3306 of your MySQL instance outside GCP from VM hosted in GCP, correct?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I can not access xx.xx.xx.xx server's database from cloud instance , I have xx.xx.xx.xx server which is hosted out side cloud , and try to access this database from cloud server , but can not

Answer (score 1):

I think your firewall rules is not correct. This one should solve the issue

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create "mysql-remote-access" \
--direction=EGRESS --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:3306 \
--destination-ranges=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32 --target-tags=mysql-client
```

*Short description: You allow the EGRESS traffic on port 3306 to the destination xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx for the traffic coming from the VM with the tag "mysql-client"*

[By default all the outgoing communication are allowed](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules), but you might have a rule with higher priority that prevents this

> Implied allow egress rule. An egress rule whose action is allow, destination is 0.0.0.0/0, and priority is the lowest possible (65535) lets any instance send traffic to any destination, except for traffic blocked by Google Cloud.

It the rule doesn't work, share all your existing firewall rules.